# Referring entity from another micro service to jdl-jhipster

Tags: java, jhipster, one-to-one, jdl

I am planing to extend the default User Entity provided by jhipster.Hence I need to create an entity say, CustomUser in a different micro service, which will be in 1-1 relationship with the default User entity.I am planning to do this using jdl. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Each **microservice** have **independent** database, so u can't create relationship with other entity because is different database. U can create one attribute in the entity CustomUser, and save the id or username in this, so u can use this for reference. 
Remember that the User entity is in the microservice of type gateway.